# GeoDjango and mobile app. Finding an address and geoposition

Tags: django-rest-framework, mobile-application, geodjango

I'm a newbie.

- There is a mobile application and a backend for Django Rest Framework
- The user should be able to select their home on the map or find it using the search bar.
- The database must contain the full address (street, house and apartment separately from the rest of the address) and geolocation (probably longitude and latitude, because later it will be necessary to search for users' homes within a certain radius from the user's current location).

Questions:

- Which of these should be implemented on the server? What is needed for this? Examples are desirable
- What should the model look like to save the address and geolocation in the database?

I would be grateful if the answers also contain links to the documentation I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made tutorial on basic usage of geodjango. Try this
https://hvitis.dev/geolocation-tutorial-geodjango-demo-and-gis-postgis-data-to-build-app-using-rest-api/#calculate-points-distance

Comment: With the help of your article, I found all the answers. As time will be, I will indicate the received solution in the question

Comment: Thanks! Glad to hear that